# Which namespace to use for the function fn:parse-xml() in xquery?

Tags: exist-db, xquery-3.0

When I am using `fn:parse-xml` in existDB getting error as:

> Function `fn:parse-xml()` is not defined in module namespace: http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions

Please help.

Comment: what is the error you see? please post your code so we can see what you've tried and try to help you

Comment: I want to convert string into xml in existsDB.                         declare  namespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
let $x  := <test> {
    
for $hit in (//xhtml:p[ft:query(., 'Stress')])
let $expanded := util:expand($hit, "expand-xincludes=yes")
   for $i at $index in ($expanded//exist:match)[1]
return (fn:replace(xs:string($hit),$i,fn:concat('<b>',$i,'</b>'))) 
} 
</test>
return util:parse($x) or fn:parse($x)

Answer (score 1):

> For questions, please specify the eXist-db version you are using.

This function has has been added to the code base quite recently in half march 2014 ([commit message](https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/commit/861e29b5808a82deb89df203b585168d47ae27cf%20commit)) and has not been available in a release yet: 2.2RC1 is dated early february 2014.

The function will be available in 2.2RC2 and onwards.